# I'm struggling to implement a subclass of UIDynamicBehavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, objective-c-blocks, uikit-dynamics

I'm trying to move a `UIView` across the screen.

`UIGravityBehavior` and `UIPushBehavior` both take things like density, velocity and friction into account. I tried to implement my own dynamic behavior that ignores those physics.

My `UIDynamicBehavior` subclass and some basic implementation

```
// MYDynamicBehavior.h
@interface MYDynamicBehavior : UIDynamicBehavior
- (void)addItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item;
- (void)removeItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item;
@end

// MYDynamicBehavior.m
@interface MYDynamicBehavior ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
@end

@implementation MYDynamicBehavior
- (void (^)(void))action
{
    __weak MYDynamicBehavior *weakSelf = self;
    for (UIView *item in weakSelf.items)
        item.center = CGPointMake(item.center.x + 10.0, item.center.y);
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        __weak MYDynamicBehavior *weakSelf = self;
        weakSelf.action = ^{
            for (UIView *item in weakSelf.items)
                item.center = CGPointMake(item.center.x + 10.0, item.center.y);
        };
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item
{
    [self.items addObject:item];
}
@end

// ViewController.m
// #includes
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDynamicAnimator *ani;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *kin;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MYDynamicBehavior *skywalk;
@end

@implementation ViewController
…
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ani = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] init];
    self.kin = // some view
    self.skywalk = [[MYDynamicBehavior alloc] init];
    [self.ani addBehavior:self.skywalk];
    [self.skywalk addItem:kin];
}
@end
```

*I'm trying to recreate this from memory, I think the basics are here*

Anyway, it's my impression from the documentation that the action property is where I need to implement my animation. It doesn't appear that my action black is ever called, however.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058595/how-to-implement-custom-uidynamicbehavior-action) is the closest I've come to a solution, but I still haven't solved this problem yet.

What am I missing? Why isn't my custom `UIDynamicBehavior` subclass working?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found the documentation that states this explicitly, and I can't guess at the underlying reason, but I have found that if my custom `UIDynamicBehavior` classes call their action blocks ***only if there is a child behavior added which has at least one item in it.***

It's weird enough that I think I'm experiencing a side effect rather than this working as intended, but that does reliably get the action block to fire. Would be really interested if anybody could shed light on the *why*, though. :1